# how to bind v-model to a specific array element in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to bind v-model to a specific array element like the following, is this possible?

```
<input v-model='item[1]' />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    items: ["Item1", "Item2"]
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="vue-instance">
  <input v-model='items[0]'/>  
  <div v-for="item in items">
    {{item}} 
  </div>
</div>
```